# Laravel's call method bypasses filters

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpunit

I am trying to run Unit Tests for Laravel using PHPUnit.

My calls to the functions seem to get to the controller, however, they seem to bypass my filters. The filters are used in order to do user validation, session tokens and so not. The call seems to go directly to the controller and forgets about the filters.

```
    public function testBasicExample(){

        $response = $this->call('GET', 'URL_Here', array('param_1' => 'value_1', 'param_2' => 'value_2' ));

        echo $response->getContent(); /**This should not be returning true if values are wrong and it is **/

        $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
```

}

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Laravel documentation, the route filters are disabled when in the testing environment. You can use the following call to enable them:

```
Route::enableFilters();
```

You can read more about this [here](http://laravel.com/docs/testing#calling-routes-from-tests). The **Note** block at the end of that chapter answers your question.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the Request object is also disabled?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Are you experiencing any problems with this? All it does is setup the Request object so that it fits the console environment it's running in

Comment: I am. I can access the header when I send requests from a browser, but they don't go when I use PHPUnit.

Comment: Oh and the enableFilters() functioned worked, thanks!